# Automapper: map many-to-many

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, many-to-many, automapper

I have the following model:

```
public class Device
{
    public string DeviceId { get; set; }
    public string DeviceName { get; set; }

    private ICollection<TagDevice> _tagDevices;
    public virtual ICollection<TagDevice> TagDevices { get => _tagDevices ?? (_tagDevices = new List<TagDevice>()); protected set => _tagDevices = value; }

}

public class Tag : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    private ICollection<TagDevice> _tagDevices;
    public virtual ICollection<TagDevice> TagDevices { get => _tagDevices ?? (_tagDevices = new List<TagDevice>()); protected set => _tagDevices = value; }
}


public class TagDevice
{
    public int TagId { get; set; }
    public string DeviceId { get; set; }

    public virtual Tag Tag { get; set; }
    public virtual Device Device { get; set; }
}
```

I have DTO class:

```
public class TagDisplayDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdatedAt { get; set; }
    public int TimesUsed { get; set; }
    public int CarrierId { get; set; }
}

public class DeviceDisplayDto
{
    public string DeviceId { get; set; }
    public string DeviceName { get; set; }

    public List<TagDisplayDto> Tags { get; set; }    
}
```

now, I want to create mapping for DeviceDisplayDto with Tags filled:

```
        CreateMap<Device, DeviceDisplayDto>()
            .ForMember(d => d.Tags, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.TagDevices...))
            ;
```

`TagDevices` is collection and not a Tag type, each element of collection has property with Tag type. How to create it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Select()` on collection of `TagDevice`s to transform it into list of `TagDisplayDto`s:

```cs
CreateMap<Device, DeviceDisplayDto>()
    .ForMember(deviceDisplayDto => deviceDisplayDto.Tags, options =>
        options.MapFrom(device => device.TagDevices.Select(tagDevice => new TagDisplayDto
        {
            CarrierId = 123,                // TODO
            CreatedAt = DateTime.UtcNow,    // TODO
            Id = tagDevice.TagId,
            Name = tagDevice.Tag.Name,
            TimesUsed = 0,                  // TODO
            UpdatedAt = DateTime.UtcNow,    // TODO
        }).ToList()));
```

I marked some properties as TODO since I don't know the whole model you are using and some properties are missing. You'll need to fill it out on your own. At least that code should get you started.

#### Edit #1

As Lucian suggested, even better solution is to fully use AutoMapper functionality. Create mappings between two models:

- from `Device` to `DeviceDisplayDto`
- from `TagDevice` to `TagDisplayDto`

```cs
CreateMap<Device, DeviceDisplayDto>()
    .ForMember(deviceDisplayDto => deviceDisplayDto.Tags, options =>
        options.MapFrom(device => device.TagDevices));
CreateMap<TagDevice, TagDisplayDto>()
    .ForMember(tagDisplayDto => tagDisplayDto.CarrierId, options =>
        options.MapFrom(tagDevice => 123))                          // TODO
    .ForMember(tagDisplayDto => tagDisplayDto.CreatedAt, options =>
        options.MapFrom(tagDevice => DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-60))) // TODO
    .ForMember(tagDisplayDto => tagDisplayDto.Id, options =>
        options.MapFrom(tagDevice => tagDevice.TagId))
    .ForMember(tagDisplayDto => tagDisplayDto.Name, options =>
        options.MapFrom(tagDevice => tagDevice.Tag.Name))
    .ForMember(tagDisplayDto => tagDisplayDto.TimesUsed, options =>
        options.MapFrom(tagDevice => 0))                            // TODO
    .ForMember(tagDisplayDto => tagDisplayDto.UpdatedAt, options =>
        options.MapFrom(tagDevice => DateTime.UtcNow));             // TODO
```

That way, mapping logic defined above is reusable. Similarly to my first solution, you'd have to fill out properties marked with `TODO` on your own.

Comment: That's manual. You just need the MapFrom and a map instead of Select.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu, I updated my answer. Feel free to add more feedback.